# Print the power of 10 - Printf in C

Tags: c, printing, printf

I have to print the powers of 10 ranging from 0-19. The problem is when I want to display the first power, which should be 1 `(10^0)`, I just can't force `printf` to not repeat the 0's whatsoever. I am allowed to only use one `printf` in my program and one `{ }` block (which is main function).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int power = 19;
    for (int i = 0; i <= power; i++)
        printf("1%0*d\n",i, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

**My output:**

```
10 // this should be 1, but printf still puts 0 here
10
100
1000
10000
100000
1000000
10000000
100000000
1000000000
10000000000
100000000000
1000000000000
10000000000000
100000000000000
1000000000000000
10000000000000000
100000000000000000
1000000000000000000
10000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `%d`, use `%s` with a variable precision, and have it print from a string of zeros.  If the precision is 0, no characters are printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int power = 19;
    char zeros[] = "00000000000000000000";
    for (int i = 0; i <= power; i++)
        printf("1%.*s\n",i, zeros);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see, so it only takes a certain range from the char. Really clever, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178141/print-the-power-of-10-printf#comment93246371_53178141), use `unsigned long long` with can handle values up to at least 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 or 2<sup>64</sup> - 1.

```
int main(void) {
  unsigned long long power = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
    printf("%d %llu\n", i, power = power ? power*10 : 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0 1
1 10
2 100
...
17 100000000000000000
18 1000000000000000000
19 10000000000000000000
```

---

Or if one does not like to hard code initialization stings like `"00000000000000000000"`,  assign the elements in the same loop.

Note `"%.*s"` can print a non- *null character* terminated `char` array.

```
#define MAX10POWER 30

int main(void) {
  char zeros[MAX10POWER];
  for (int i = 0; i <= MAX10POWER; zeros[i++] = '0')
    printf("%d 1%.*s\n", i, i, zeros);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0 1
1 10
2 100
...
28 10000000000000000000000000000
29 100000000000000000000000000000
30 1000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

Or a sneaky variation of [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53178683/2410359) good answer to go up to 21.

```
int main(void) {
  for (unsigned long long power = 1, i = 0; i <= 21; i++, power *= 8)
    printf("%lld %llo\n", i, power);
}
```

Comment: OP 's requirement is for a single pair of braces, the body of `main` :(

Comment: @WeatherVane Back to 1 set of `{}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired result like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned long long power = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++, power *= 10)
        printf("%llu\n", power);
    return 0;
}
```